# Redirect add-on website from https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have 2 websites in my hosting account at bluehost. The main domain (maindomain.com) has an SSL and there is one registration page where I need to use https//www.maindomain.com.

I also have an add-on domain (addondomain.com) and am hosting the website for that in the same account. There is no necessity for a secure connection.

However, I want to make sure that if https://addonsite.com is used, it redirects to http://addonsite.com. The reason is that now if you go to https://addonsite.com, it shows that in the URL address window, but the maindomain.com website loads.

I have tried adding redirects to both .htaccess files (for maindomain.com and addondomain.com), but cannot seem to get it to work. Is it possible to do this with a main domain and add on domain if there is an SSL on the main domain?

Comment: show how the redirect you are using looks like.

Comment: htaccess for maindomain.com:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?calbf\.org$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ https://www.calbf.org/$1 [R,L] 
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

Comment: Here is the .htaccess for the maindomain.com:

Comment: put them in the question , I cant read it here is no linefeed